# asp.net c# server not seeing change in data from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have an asp.net webform where the user can enter data and submit into a database table on sql-server-2008

1. the user picks the primary key of the record he wants to edit by going to the URL http://someurl/default.aspx?primarykey=123
2. based on the primary key the webform is succesfully filled out
3. the user can make changes to any data and resubmit it to be updated in the database for that specific PK

here is how i grab data from the userform:

```
    public LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
    {
        //populate class
        LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form TheForm = new LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form();

        try
        {
            TheForm.received_date = received_dateTextbox.Text.ToDateTime();
            TheForm.site_of_occurrence = site_of_occurrenceTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
            TheForm.occurrence_date = occurrence_dateTextBox.Text.ToDateTime();
            TheForm.report_by = report_byTextBox.Text;


            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Other:")
                TheForm.identified_by = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
            else
                TheForm.identified_by = "Other: " + otherTextBox.Text;


            TheForm.practice_code = txtPracticeCode.Text.ToUpper();
            TheForm.comments = txtComments.Text;
            TheForm.report_date = report_dateTextBox.Text.ToDateTime();
            //TheForm.windows_user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            TheForm.windows_user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            TheForm.computer_name = System.Environment.MachineName;
            TheForm.time_stamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return TheForm;
    }
```

it is returning OLD data. it returns what was in the fields BEFORE the user updated the data in the textboxes.

another words when i debug, and i look at the values that are being stored in the textboxes they DO NOT reflect the changes made by the user. the values are the same as they are currently in the database before the update!

what am i doing wrong?

is there some kind of disconnect between client and server?

Comment: You don't show us when and how you pull the data out, that's pretty important, as well as putting it back in.

Comment: if there are any questions at all about my post please let me know and i will immediately answer

Comment: @mr disa just curious why would that be relevant. perhaps my wording is misleading

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment the thing is even BEFORE putting the data back in, it reads the text incorrectly

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment  the thing is im reading the data from the form AFTER it is being repopulated

Comment: Are you calling `PopulateNewForm()` from your Page Load event?

Comment: @coding no i am calling it on BUTTON CLICK (submit)

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment i am just using asp.net textboxes, not forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check your bindings when you load the page. Chances are you are re-binding your page from your database before you try to read the changed values.

Check your Page_Load and make sure you are only binding your page with database information when !Page.IsPostBack and not every time you load your page.